# What is the power plug in the photo called?

Tags: connector, identification

Is the plug shown in the photo, which looks like IEC 320 but with angular tips, standard? If so what is it called?

[image: photo]

Comment: chances are that this is a proprietary backpanel connector, considering this looks like a server PSU. Manufacturer and type of device we're looking at?

Comment: It's not a standard type. See [IEC 60320](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320).

Comment: Is this from china?  it looks like a Type-I connection (used in china and australia) but within a standard IEC body

Comment: It is vaguely but not really like China or New Zealand or Australia's plug.  For a start, its intended for a line cord not a direct wall socket connection.

Comment: I'm guessing its a proprietary connector, because its intended for 277V AC which is beyond what most equipment would expect.  So its HP being "safe" while charging a lot for the item.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently, there are HP server power supplies that have a non-standard connection.
They are found on [ParallelMiner](https://www.parallelminer.com/product/platinum-1200-watt-200-240v-power-supply-kit-for-gpu-mining-zec-dash-eth/#) as KT-1200-200V-1 for example.

> We use a custom 12inch power cord to bypass the proprietary AC plug

Behold the custom cable:

[image: C13UNIVERSAL]

It's just a [cable with quick-connects](https://www.parallelminer.com/product/1ft-14awg-universal-ac-power-cord-to-c13-up-to-300v-rated/).

---

Apparently this is the 277VAC version of the power supply:

*HP 1200W Common Slot 277VAC Hot Plug Power Supply Kit (717359-B21).*

The plug and socket are called **LS-25** and **LS-26**. (an adapter is sold by stuartconnections)
HP also sells adapter TK801A and TK802A.

[image]

([source](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04111541.pdf))

Comment: I could see that coming. +1

Comment: I don't see diagonal blades on your picture nor in the link. Can you explain how this answers the question?

Comment: @Andyaka Click "parallelminer" link in his answer. Basically HP seems to want $$$ for their custom connector, so everyone uses spade lug quick connects instead. Safety is our number one priority!

Comment: @Andyaka It's also the wrong gender. You're supposed to use the loose quick connects on the non-standard plug.

Comment: Not wrong gender - the other end is connected to a standard IEC cable it seems. What I *hate* about the makeshift cable shown is that the PE seems not substantially *longer*. BTW, that might not just be a cash grab - the standard C13/C14 system has a horrible tendency to be intermittent and too easily pulled/yanked out by accident, not at all fun around servers - and might also be out of ampacity if 1200W if there is an identical 110V version. Why ever they did not use C19/C20, though...

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at [IEC World Plugs,](http://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/) it does look similar to an IEC Type I male connector, however, one of the blades is rotated 90 degrees.

[image]

My guess is that it is a proprietary connector to avoid the possibiility of connecting the supply without a cable from the manufacturer.

Comment: this design has to be changed for esthetic reasons. it triggers the facial expression recognition circuits in my brain and makes me depressed.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I see it as well.  It's is a truly sad design for an electric outlet :-) .

Comment: And that image is identical arrangement to an Australia/New Zealand power connector.   And the same as China although rotated 180 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

The male inlet on the power supply is a LS-25. It accepts a power cord with a LS-26 connector/outlet.